# SQL Server - organising dates into a view from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for the broad title as I was unsure on how to word it but here is what I am after doing:

I have a table called `Scanner` and it contains a `ScannerID` (Primary Key), `StaffID`, `EventTime` and `Status`. This table records each time a scan occurs on a device and records it into this table on `EventTime`. The `StaffID` identifies who it is based on the cards details. Finally the `Status` counts up each time a scan is recorded based on the `StaffID`, for example:

```
  ScannerID          StaffID          EventTime          Status
      1                 1         2016-06-24 07:30:00      1
      2                 1         2016-06-24 13:00:00      2
      3                 1         2016-06-24 14:00:00      3
      4                 1         2016-06-24 17:00:00      4
      5                 2         2016-06-24 08:30:00      1
      6                 2         2016-06-24 17:30:00      2
```

**Question**
from this data I want to be able to block these together within a view like below, for example:

```
StaffID          StartDate                 EndDate     
   1         2016-06-24 07:30:00      2016-06-24 13:00:00 
   1         2016-06-24 14:00:00      2016-06-24 17:00:00
```

this is based on odd numbers from `Status` being the StartDate, and Even Numbers from `Status` being the EndDate.

Additional Information

- The Status starts from 1 each day, and increments based on the StaffID
- **Clarification**: odd numbers are StartDate's and even are EndDate's. This is because the card is scanned an unknown quantity, but will always end on an Even number as they cannot leave the building without scanning out. That is the premises I am working on in my design

Is this possible to do, and if so how can I go about creating a view, alternativly what options are available to me with data like shown in the singular breakdown?

Thankyou for all help and advice on this matter

Comment: 1 Start 4 end for status?

Comment: odd numbers are StartDate's and even are EndDate's. This is because the card is scanned an unknown quantity, but will always end on an Even number as they cannot leave the building without scanning out. That is the premises I am working on in my design

Comment: Do you have any parent id?

Comment: yes the table contains a primary key, ill add it above

Comment: Does status count incrment per staffid. If stafidd came in as 1 does it have to exit as 2 or it can exit as 4

Comment: in theory on how I have designed it yes, all even numbers are the exit, and all odd are entry. if there is a better way of doing this that you can thing off ill apply it above to my design. and yes again, the status increments on a daily basis, based on the StaffID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
CREATE TABLE #Scanning(StaffID INT, EventTime DATETIME, Status INT)

INSERT INTO #Scanning
VALUES  
    (1, '2016-06-24 07:30:00',  1)
   ,(1, '2016-06-24 13:00:00',  2)
   ,(1, '2016-06-24 14:00:00',  3)
   ,(1, '2016-06-24 17:00:00',  4)
   ,(1, '2016-06-25 07:30:00',  1)
   ,(1, '2016-06-25 13:00:00',  2)
   ,(1, '2016-06-25 14:00:00',  3)
   ,(1, '2016-06-25 17:00:00',  4)

SELECT  s1.StaffID, 
        s1.EventTime AS StartDate,
        s2.EventTime AS EndDate
FROM #Scanning s1
LEFT JOIN #Scanning s2 ON s1.StaffID = s2.StaffID
    AND s2.Status = s1.Status + 1
    AND CAST(s1.EventTime AS DATE) = CAST(s2.EventTime AS DATE) -- match for each day..
WHERE s1.Status%2 = 1       -- only rows with odd Numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple Group By StaffID,((Status+1)/2) will do the trick

You could even add min/max scanner

```
Declare @Table table (ScannerID int,StaffID int,EventTime Datetime,Status int)
Insert into @Table values 
(1,1,'2016-06-24 07:30:00',1),
(2,1,'2016-06-24 13:00:00',2),
(3,1,'2016-06-24 14:00:00',3),
(4,1,'2016-06-24 17:00:00',4)

Select StaffID
      ,StartDate = min(EventTime)
      ,EndDate   = max(EventTime)
 From  @Table
 Group By StaffID,((Status+1)/2)
 Order By 1,2


StaffID StartDate               EndDate
1       2016-06-24 07:30:00.000 2016-06-24 13:00:00.000
1       2016-06-24 14:00:00.000 2016-06-24 17:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add parent id to your table.

```
StaffID          EventTime          Status  PKId  ParentPKId
1         2016-06-24 07:30:00       1       1     0
1         2016-06-24 13:00:00       2       2     1
1         2016-06-24 14:00:00       3       3     0
1         2016-06-24 17:00:00       4       4     3
```

Then

```
 SELECT
    A.StaffID,
    A.EventTime AS StartDate,
    B.EventTime AS EndDate     
 FROM
    TABLE A LEFT JOIN
    TABLE B ON A.PKId = B.ParentPKId
 WHERE 
    A.Status % 2 = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
   *
From
  (
    Select staffid, eventtime, status from table 
     Where cast (status as float) % 2 =0
  ) as enters
  Left outher  join (
  Select staaffid ,eventtime , statsus from table
  Where cast (status as float) % 2 >0
) as exits on enters.staffid=exits.staffid and enters.status+1= exits.statsu
```